# How to keep only current annotation marker in MapKit on iOS (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I would like to display my current location using MapKit (MapView) from external GPS coordinates (not using iphone location services). Annotation marker displaying location of new coordinates should be the only one i want to keep, instead all previous annotations are kept. Coordinate values are updated from ContentView (retrieved externally there).

How do i display only the current annotation marker (with most recent location)?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
var longi = 34.011286
var lati = -116.166868


func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    MKMapView(frame: .zero)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {


    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: lati, longitude: longi)
    let pinpoa=MKPointAnnotation()
    pinpoa.coordinate=coordinate
    pinpoa.title="CAR"
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    uiView.addAnnotation(pinpoa)
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you add a new annotation, you just need to remove the one/s already on the map. So:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)
    let pinpoa=MKPointAnnotation()
    pinpoa.coordinate=coordinate
    pinpoa.title="CAR"
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
    uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotations = mapView.annotations
    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)  // REMOVE THEM HERE

    uiView.addAnnotation(pinpoa)
}
```